# How to start Electron.NET blazor app on windows start?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, electron.net

I am working on a project that uses Electron.NET and Blazor. I am looking for a solution how to start it automatically on OS(Win || MAC || Linux) start.
ElectronNET.API -> Version="9.31.2"
.NET Version = netcoreapp3.1

Answer (score 0):

There is a folder in Windows 10/11 located at `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.  If you put a shortcut to your app in there it will run at startup for the current user.

If you want to run at startup for all users you will need:

1. admin escalation
2. create a task in Windows Task Scheduler with the trigger `When the computer starts`

I don't know how to do any of that on a Mac/Linux, but likely the basic process will be the same:

- find an o/s specific way of starting a program
- get your app to detect the platform it's running on
- invoke said process putting shortcuts, links or config entries in the right places

I don't think Electron/ElectronNET has any specific helpers for this sort of thing.

There is an npm library called `auto-launch` that you would use if you were building Electron rather than ElectronNET. See [NPM - auto-launch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-launch) and also [this article on how to use it in Electron](https://mohammedlakkadshaw.com/blog/how-to-auto-start-electron-applications-on-startup.html/). You might be able to port something into your app from there.